# Typescript package to one .js file

Tags: typescript, npm

I have some typescript library downloaded from GitHub
I see many dependencies to other npm packages
Is it possible to built it to one .js file by npm, webpack etc?
I want to avoid "export/import" js features but just one big .js file
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what a bundler can do for you. It takes your separate source files and bundles them into a single file.

Take a look at Parcel or Rollup for example: https://parceljs.org/typeScript.html, https://github.com/rollup/rollup

Comment: Thanks! It is what I need